# gradle: Execute task "type:Exec" with many arguments with spaces

Tags: batch-file, gradle, exec, spaces, processbuilder

I have the gradle task that should create Websphere profile on Windows OS

```
task createProfile(type:Exec) {

    def commandToExecute = new StringBuffer()
    def profile = 'AppSrv02'
    def wasHome = 'C:/IBM new/WebSphere/AppServer'

    def str = new LinkedList <String> ();
    str.add('cmd')
    str.add('/c')
    str.add(wasHome + '/bin/manageprofiles.bat')
    str.add('-create')
    str.add('-profileName')
    str.add(profile)
    //str.add('-templatePath')
    //str.add(wasHome + '/profileTemplates/default')

    println (str)
    commandLine str.toArray()

}
```

And the problem appears if I uncomment commented lines, after it task fails and say me that: "C:/IBM" is not valid batch file. If I put profileTemplates not in the folder that contains spaces, everything works fine again. But templates should lies int wasHome( And sometimes wasHome has spaces(

I have, now ideas why adding templates key with value with spaces influence in such way that Gradle tries to start "C:/IBM" instead specified 'C:/IBM new/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/manageprofiles.bat'. It seems that, possibly, problem inside java.lang.ProcessBuilder.

I tries to quote paths, by adding   `"/""`  but nothing works(((( what isn't surprise, because ProcessBuilder implies quoting by itself if it is needed.

So, I am asking if anybody had the similar problem and could recommend how to work around this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If somebody needed it, we found a workaround for this problem. The task finally looks like:

```
task createProfile(type: Exec) {
    executable = new File(wsadminLocation, manageProfilesFileName)
    def templatePath = wasHome + File.separator + "profileTemplates" + File.separator + "default"
    def argsList = ["-create", "-profileName", profile, "-templatePath", templatePath, "-nodeName", nodeName, "-cellName", wasCellName, "-enableAdminSecurity", isProfileSecured, "-adminUserName", rootProject.wasLogin, "-adminPassword", rootProject.wasPassword]
    args = argsList
}
```

The basic idea is to pass the arguments to the Gradle not as long string, but as a list. So in this way there aren't any problems if an argument contains a space.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I had an argument such as `--autoprefix="last 2 versions"`, and the spaces inbetween the doublequotes were always throwing things off.

Answer (score 3):

Change following lines

```
def wasHome = '"C:/IBM new/WebSphere/AppServer'
...
str.add(wasHome + '/bin/manageprofiles.bat"')
```

That way, the full path to the batch file is quoted.

EDITED - As stated by dbenhan, a little obfuscated. This "should" be something like

```
task createProfile(type:Exec) {

    def commandToExecute = new StringBuffer()
    def profile = 'AppSrv02'
    def wasHome = 'C:/IBM new/WebSphere/AppServer'

    def str = new LinkedList <String> ();
    str.add('cmd')
    str.add('/c')
    str.add('"' + wasHome + '/bin/manageprofiles.bat"')
    str.add('-create')
    str.add('-profileName')
    str.add(profile)
    str.add('-templatePath')
    str.add('"' + wasHome + '/profileTemplates/default"')

    println (str)
    commandLine str.toArray()

}
```

BUT, while gradle in particular and windows in general can handle paths with slash separators, i have no idea if `manageprofiles.bat` can, and you are passing a parameter with a path in it. Maybe, you will need to change your paths to `'c:\\IBM new\\....'`

Comment: +1, or perhaps a bit less obfuscated: `str.add('"'+wasHome+'/bin/manageprofiles.bat"')`

Comment: @dbenham: i know. But this allows to uncomment the following two lines and use `str.add(wasHome + '/profileTemplates/default"')` reusing the initial quote (just joking, you are right ;-) )

Comment: tried both, still the same result(((( still not working, somehow ant do it perfectly, with gradle I am not managed to succeed.

Comment: unfortunately, no( I added quotes: no result, changed slashes: again nothing> Even println prints
 [cmd, /c, "C:\IBM new\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\manageprofiles.bat", -create, -profileName, AppSrv02, -templatePath, "C:\IBM new\WebSphere\AppServer\profileTemplates\default"], still
command line says that "C:\IBM" is not valid command or something this

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
task xyz {
def result1 = exec {
            workingDir "D:/abc/efg"
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'CDUTIL.bat', "qwe", "rty"
        }

        println result1.toString()
}
```

Comment: this definitely works with gradle 3.5 and groovy